# Force logout currently logged in user in wss 3.0 - how to?

Tags: security, sharepoint, wss-3.0

Scenario is like this:

I have currently logged in user. This user would like to remove his own account. He clicks button, then Membership.DeleteUser function runs. After this he is still logged in into service despite that his account was successfully deleted.

How can I force to log out him after his account was deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answer is correct.

```
FormsAuthentication.Signout();
```

But there is also another way to do it:

You can create link to logout site:

```
<a href="_layouts/signout.aspx">log out</a>
```

:)

Comment: Your question is how to Force logout an User, clicking on the sign out  is something user has to do by himself, please rephrase the question.

Comment: I've just added alternate way. So wtf? GFY guys!

Comment: The point is a) Kusek's answer better fits your question (the link doesn't work in the context you describe) and b) its a bit low taking his answer (.Signout), repeating it as your own answer and then marking it as correct. Don't abuse the goodwill of posters.

Comment: I didn't copy answer because I've just add another way of doing the same, and I've rewarded Kusek voting for his answer and not for mine. So? You are just telling bullsh*ts!

Comment: You've accepted your own answer as correct (see green tick) despite the fact that it doesn't answer your own question and another poster had already answered your question. You should have accepted Kusek's answer. You now have 3 different people telling you the same. You sir need to grow up a little.

Answer (score 3):

```
FormsAuthentication.Signout();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Above two line should do the trick